# Flipping several biased coins

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assuming I'm flipping $M$ biased coins with different probability for heads $p_i, i=\{1,...,M\}$. What is the probability of having $k$ times head? Is there a distribution function known for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look for "Poisson binomial distribution", e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution

Answer (score 0):

There is no known distribution function but you can create by your own.
Order the biased coin $1,2 \ldots ,M$. Now in the binomial coefficient we have $\binom Mk \times p^k \times q^{M-k}$ . Here for a fixed $k$ it will be $ (p_{i_1}p_{i_2}p_{i_3} \ldots p_{i_k})(q_{i_1}q_{i_2}q_{i_3} \ldots q_{i_k})$ product will run over all possible choosing of $k$ in $M$. Now add them. Now construct the distribution.